# Pandas: How to sum columns on data frame based on value of another data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Pandas and I am trying to do the following thing::

- I have a dataframe called *comms* with columns articleID and commentScore (among others)
- I have another dataframe called *arts* with column articleID

I need to create in *arts* a new column called *articleScore*. Each article must have the articleScore which is the sum of all commentScores related to that article (same articleID), divided by sqrt(n_comms + 1), where n_comms is the number of comments with that specific ID.

I already managed to do this but In a very inefficient way (pictured below)

```
for article in arts:
    n, tempScore = 0
    
    for i, value in comms.iterrows():
        if value['articleID'] == article['articleID']:
            tempScore + = value['commentScore']
            n += 1    
    article['articleScore'] /= math.sqrt(n+1)
```

Edit: Here's an example of what I would like to happen:

```
comms:
__________________________
| # | artID | commScore  |
| 0 | 1x5w  |     2      |
| 1 | 77k3  |     1      |
| 2 | 77k3  |    -1      |
| 3 | 3612  |     5      |
| 4 | 1x5w  |     3      |
--------------------------

arts:
___________________________
| # | artID | artScore (?) |
| 0 | 1x5w  |    2.89      |
| 1 | 77k3  |     0        |
| 2 | 3612  |    3.54      |
-------------------------
```

I need to (create and) fill the artScore column. Each artScore is the sum of the commentScores, but only of the comments with the same artID of the article, divided by sqrt(n+1).

Can anybody help me?
Thanks a lot!

Andrea

Comment: Well, can you add a sample dataframe and your expected dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by expected dataframe?

Comment: The result that you wish to get given the sample input. Because it's a sample you can fill the result by hand. In this way, people can help you better.

Comment: Thanks I have added that. Hope someone will help now!

Comment: That's very good! But can be better if you can calculate the sample result and fill it on the DF. Also, it's better to post the DF in plain text (in code block format), rather than an image.

Comment: I've done it, thanks.

Comment: It's much more clear now. Good job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `groupby` followed by a merge on `'artID'`:

```
grpd = comms.groupby('artID')
to_merge = grpd.sum().divide(np.sqrt(grpd.count()+1)).reset_index().rename(columns={'commScore': 'artScore'})[['artID', 'artScore']]
arts.merge(to_merge, on='artID')
```

Comment: Hi @gofvonx, thanks for your answer. I did what you recommended, but now on my *arts* data frame there are a lot of unwanted columns. Plus, I don't see in your code snippet where you assign a name to the new column articleScore

Comment: @Sala I have included explicit renaming of the column and also selected only the required sub-frame to merge. (Your sample data doesn't have any additional columns.) Does that work?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
#article count and sum
df = df.groupby('artID').agg(['sum', 'count'])

#create new column and utilize your formula
df['artScore'] = df['commScore']['sum'] / math.sqrt(df['commScore']['count']+1)


    commScore   artScore
       sum  count   
artID           
1x5w    5   2   5.0
3612    5   1   5.0
77k3    0   2   0.0
```

Comment: I believe this code is not correct as it does not take the square-root.

Comment: you are right. I fixed it. thanks.@gofvonx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` with `agg` and a custom `lambda` function to apply to each group:

```py
comms.groupby('artID').agg(
    {'commScore': lambda x: x.sum() / np.sqrt(len(x) + 1)}
).reset_index().rename(columns={'commScore': 'artScore'})
```

Result:

```sh
  artID  artScore
0  1x5w  2.886751
1  3612  3.535534
2  77k3  0.000000
```