# pandas: groupby + store in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67139587/pandas-how-to-sum-columns-on-data-frame-based-on-value-of-another-data-frame) last week and now I have a similar issue, but I cannot convert the answer I received in this case.

Basically, I have a dataframe called comms which looks like this:

```
articleID   Material    commentScore
 1234         News          0.75      
 1234         News          -0.1      
 5678         Sport         1.33      
 5678         News          0.75      
 5678        Fashion        0.02 
 7412       Politics        -3.45
```

and another dataframe called arts and it looks like this:

```
articleID   wordCount      byLine
 1234         1524          John     
 5678         9824          Mary    
 7412         3713          Sam
```

I would like to simply count how many `comms` there are for each `articleID`, and store this number in a new column of the `arts` dataframe named `commentNumber`.

I think I have to use `groupby`, `count()` and maybe `merge`, but I can't figure out why.

Expected output

```
articleID   wordCount      byLine    commentNumber
 1234         1524          John         2
 5678         9824          Mary         3
 7412         3713          Sam          1
```

Thanks in advance!
Andrea

Comment: What is your expected/desired output? Please provide a sample dataframe with the processed data.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot to provide it. Edited now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby()` then `count()` on one column. At last, map the result with `articleID` columns of `arts`.

```py
arts['commentNumber'] = arts['articleID'].map(comms.groupby('articleID')['Material'].count())
```

```
print(arts)

   articleID  wordCount byLine  commentNumber
0       1234       1524   John              2
1       5678       9824   Mary              3
2       7412       3713    Sam              1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
arts['commentNumber'] = arts['articleID'].map(comms['articleID'].value_counts())
print (arts)
   articleID  wordCount byLine  commentNumber
0       1234       1524   John              2
1       5678       9824   Mary              3
2       7412       3713    Sam              1
```

Alternative:

```
from collections import Counter
arts['commentNumber'] = arts['articleID'].map(Counter(comms['articleID']))
```

Comment: This is not dupe?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - I think not, `transform` is not possible use here. But is it really close last answer - only for 2 different df.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - But maybe find better dupe, let me know, then I can close

Comment: Fair enough but i guess its almost similar.